# how to set master detail for popup in oracle adf

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have oracle 11gr2 and JDeveloper 11.1.2.1.0
I have 3 tables , that are master detail detail . 
I want to use pop up for these master and details tables .
Can i do it ?
Is popup support the master and detail tables ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just create a button with `<af:showPopupBehavior popupId='mypopup'` to open the popup and a `<af:popup id='mypopup'><af:dialog>` structure in which you copy the contents which are currently in the `<af:showDetailItem`

Answer (score 0):

you can everything in popup that you are doing in page , it is nothing just a container on page in second layer
see-http://andrejusb.blogspot.in/2009/11/crud-operations-in-oracle-adf-11g-table.html
http://andrejusb.blogspot.in/2009/03/adf-faces-rich-client-popup-and-master.html

Thanks

Comment: you say popup is the same as page, but i can not create an adf table in popup. how can i do that?!

Comment: have you seen link share above ?
Just select viewObject in data control and drop it on dialog inside popup as a table
http://www.awasthiashish.com/2012/11/popup-component-in-oracle-adf.html